# How to install Spring Source and Sink

Tags: spring-xd

I am just getting started on Spring XD, watched a few demos on youtube, and the one that I am referencing here is this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyB5KVykaWQ&amp=&feature=youtu.be

I have setup the current release version 1.2.1, with FLO, and I was trying to reproduce the demo.
It shows multiple sources and sinks, like http, log etc. Plus, there are a ton of sources mentioned here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#sources
and sinks http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#sinks

But I do not see these sources/sinks. I only see gemfire/cq, redis, jdbc, rabbit, kafka, twitterstream and twittersearch

How to install rest of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded version 1.3 M1, and that had every source and sink I was looking for.